# What is the smallest direct band gap ever achieved so far and how small is it?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

I have read that a material called stanene has an indirect band gap around 80 meV. But have any direct band gap semiconductors ever gotten that low?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Mercury Cadmium Telluride (MCT) can be made with direct bandgap going all the way down to zero. It is often used for detectors in the very long wavelengths. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_cadmium_telluride

Comment: Actually, you can even achieve negative gaps in HgTe/CdTe quantum wells. Although, I admit that this is hard to rationalize.